# Spring: Chain filter after jwt token filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Here my current `SecurityFilterChain`:

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        final CorsConfigurationSource configurationSource = serverWebExchange -> {
            final var cc = new CorsConfiguration();
            cc.addAllowedOriginPattern(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
            cc.addAllowedMethod(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
            cc.addAllowedHeader(CorsConfiguration.ALL);

            return cc;
        };

        // Customizer<OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity>> oauth2Customizer = (config) -> config.opaqueToken();
        Customizer<OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity>> oauth2Customizer = (config) -> config.jwt();

        return http
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .anonymous().disable()
            .logout().disable()
            .cors().configurationSource(configurationSource).and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/gicar/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2Customizer)
            .build();
    }
```

Everything is working.

From now on, I'd like to add a filter in order to check:

1. `"app"` query parameter is present in to request.
2. `"app"` query parameter value is equals to token claim `"clientId"` value.

In order to get current token claim `"clientId"` value code snippet is:

```java
JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthenticationToken = (JwtAuthenticationToken) this.httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal();
Jwt jwt = (Jwt) jwtAuthenticationToken.getPrincipal();
String clientId = jwt.getClaim("clientId");
```

In order to get current `"app"` query param value code snippet:

```java
String user = this.httpServletRequest.getParameter("app");
```

Any ideas about:

1. how to embed above code in a filter?
2. how to chain this filter after authentication filter?